# Remove background color within jsp tags in Netbeans IDE

Tags: jsp, netbeans

I have been using [NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/) for php development and really like it. I have recently started working on a project that contains a lot of jsp files.

I have been trying to find in the color prefs where I can remove the background? color that shows any time there are jsp tags: `<% %>`

Anything inside of those tags gets a light-green color and it's almost impossible to read. I haven't found anything other than "Change your colors in your preferences". I understand how to do that - I just haven't been able to find which setting that is.

Has anyone come across this before? I have attached a screen shot to help show what I'm talking about. Thank you for your time![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tools|Options|Fonts & Colors -> Syntax, select JSP and select "JSP Scriptlet" and "JSP Scriptlet Delimiter".